Is there a function for changing text value to numeric value in a calculate field in a pivot table in Excel sheet?
I used a formula in the calculate field in a pivot table and it returned #VALUE! error stating "Function AVERAGE in parameter 1 expected number values but Box Office Revenue ($) is text and cannot be coerced into a number.
I tried formatting the text by highlighting the column clicked format then numbers and currency. I expected the #VALUE! error in the calculate field row to change but it didn't and still insisted that the BOX OFFICE REVENUE Column was still in text instead of numbers.

Your title says Excel sheet, but you tagged it Google Sheets. Which one is it? They are not the same thing, and have different functionality. Also, you're asking us to explain why a formula you didn't include in your post isn't working on data you also did not include in your post.

Thanks for calling this to my attention. Firstly it is Google sheet and secondly the formula I used in the Calculate field is = AVERAGE("Box Office Revenue ($) - AVERAGE("Budget ($)"). and it returned a #VALUE! error

Then edit your question and remove the reference to Excel from the title. You can add your formula example to the post during that same edit, so it's where it belongs and can be seen.

Hi have you tried putting box office as currency(Google spreadsheet) like this
enter image description here

Yes I have it still didn't work. Please it seems we are working on the same project and I am stuck badly. How do I reach out to you, I need all the help I can get. Thank you

I complet the steps for this activity, i upload my file in drobbox
Creat an account and download the xlsx file
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/elvs7j9wqbrm0zr57ktnl/Movie-Data-Starter-Project-1.xlsx?rlkey=cyjgljte03v37zv4nlur0h7w5&st=9n3ldg49&dl=0
